# PostgreSQL-13 The connection pool has been exhausted

Tags: postgresql-performance, postgresql-13

Hope all of you are doing well!.

Our ASP NetCore 3.1 Web API runs on CentOS 8 with Postgresql-13, currently, we are facing the following error:

Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): The connection pool has been exhausted, either raise MaxPoolSize (currently 30) or Timeout (currently 15 seconds)

Our server specs:

RAM 16GB

Our configs:

```
/etc/sysctl.conf
kernel.shmmax=100663296

/var/lib/pgsql/13/data/postgresql.conf
max_connection=100
shared_buffer=512
```

Comment: Well you _application_ needs more than the 30 connection it defined in its own connection pool. You probably have a connection leak in your application code, where connections aren't returned to the pool. This all happens on the application side, Postgres is not involved here, so you need to fix your application.